# C# clone static class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have studied deep copies over the day but I still don't quite get it.

Here's what I want.

**static class MyList**

```
List<MenuData> Menu1 = MenuList.Menus.ToList();
List<MenuData> Menu2 = MenuList.Menus.ToList();
```

I use Menu2 on remove method.
However, Menu1 was also deleted.
I realize that Menu1 and Menu2 were deleted together because of Swallow Copy.

They also referred to samples of other people, but failed.

```
static class MenuList
{
    public class MenuData
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public Boolean Expanded { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<MenuData> Menus = new List<MenuData>()
    {
        new MenuData {
            ID = "1",
            Text = "Service",
            Image = "file_path.png",
            Expanded = false
        },
    };

    public static T Clone<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }

    public static List<MenuData> CopyMenus = MenuList.Clone(MenuList.Menus);
}
```

**ErrMessage :** `The format 'Models.MenuData' is not marked serializable.`

It was asked to reduce further waste of time.

Comment: How can cloning a `static` class make sense? Cloning is creating a copy of an object. `static` classes cannot be instantiated so you can't create an object in the first place, so how could you copy one?

Comment: Why are you declaring a class inside a `static` class?

Comment: The intent of the creator is unknown.
I need one more data in static class.
However, the amount of data is high.
So I wanted to create a clone efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why did you want to clone a static class

but if you want to `Serialize` object you need to use a attribute `Serializable` to tag your Serialize Class.

```
[Serializable]
public class MenuData
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public Boolean Expanded { get; set; }
}
```

[serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/basic-serialization)

**EDIT**

If you want to clone object, your clone class can implement `ICloneable` interface.

Here is a sample.

```
public class MenuList
{
    public List<MenuData> Menus { get; private set; }

    public MenuList()
    {
        Menus = new List<MenuData>()
        {
            new MenuData {
                ID = "1",
                Text = "Service",
                Image = "file_path.png",
                Expanded = false
            },
        };
    }

    public class MenuData : ICloneable
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public Boolean Expanded { get; set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return new MenuData()
            {
                ID = this.ID,
                Text = this.Text,
                Expanded = this.Expanded,
                Image = this.Image
            };
        }
    }

    public List<MenuData> CloneMenus()
    {
        return Menus.Select(o => (MenuData)o.Clone()).ToList();
    }
}
```

You can get Clone List on outside.

```
MenuList list = new MenuList();
List<MenuData> CloneList = list.CloneMenus();
```

Comment: I want save static class Origin data.
By the way, the method changes origin static class data.
I wanted to avoid this.
My skills are still insufficient.
Can you tell me other than this?

Comment: I think you could not clone a static field.That's meaningless.You need to create a object List then clone that make sence.

Comment: thanks. i try again

Comment: @제일일 I add a sample wish can help you

Comment: Wow, Thank you for your help.
I realized what I was doing wrong.
You have modified your sauce a little to make it work.